# Calling BeforeShowDay multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a JQuery UI Datepicker widget with a `beforeShowDay` that calls a `highlightday` function. The function takes a date, and a list of dates to highlight. If the date is in the list, it gives it the "event" class.

```
function highlightday(date, highdates) {
  for (var i = 0; i < highdates.length; i++) {
    if ($.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date) === highdates[i]) {
      return [true, 'event'];
    }
  }
  return [true, ''];
}
```

This works fine. The "event" dates are labeled correctly.

The list of dates, however, is fetched from a server and only for the selected month. So if the datepicker starts off in May, the `fetchdates` function requests dates with events in May, and that's assigned to `var dates`.

The problem is when the user picks a different month. I have `onChangeMonthYear` set up to call a `changemonth` function, which is simply

```
function changemonth(year, month) {
  this.dates = fetchdates(this.id, year + "-" + month);
}
```

The `dates` variable is updated correctly, but the new dates are not highlighted because `beforeShowDay` already called `highlightday`. `refresh()` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a mistake on my part. `dates` was not being updated correctly.